# Ubuntu doesn't detect extra mouse buttons

Tags: mouse, logitech

I have Logitech G502 mouse. Problem is, half of buttons are not detected at all.

While searching all answers or tutorials I found were assuming that xev detects all buttons and were concerned with binding detected buttons. In my case xev doesn't detect most of additional buttons.

Detected buttons are:

- leftclick (event 1)
- mouse wheel press (event 2)
- rightclick (event 3)
- wheel scroll up (event 4)
- wheel scroll down (event (5)
- backwards thumb button (event 8)
- forwards thumb button (event 9)

Following are not detected:

- 3rd thumb button (1 button)
- 2 small buttons next to LMB (2 buttons)
- lateral mouse wheel press left/right (2 buttons)

Basically, only 2 out of 7 nonstandard buttons are detected.

How do I make system detect those buttons?

Comment: @NickWeinberg No. It's not duplicate. As I stated at the beginning, all answers assume that system detects the buttons. Top answer in question you linked doesn't even take into account possibility that some buttons are not detected. Heck, that answer is how I found out that system doesn't detect half my mouse buttons.

Comment: Did you try the answer posted yesterday by @user681010 ? It does not seem to assume what you're saying it does.

Comment: @NickWeinberg If I can't get system to recognize buttons, I'll try that. I would however prefer to not have to.